# Apostrophes converting to periods in HTML

Tags: html

I have a client using a CMS for a site. When they enter apostrophes, they render as periods within the HTML. I've checked the raw source, and an apostrophe (' - not a MS Word curly "smart" apostrophe) is indeed there but it renders as a period.

I've gone into the database and manually entered apostrophes thinking perhaps it was the CMS, but the problem persists. I've seen the "diamond question mark" unrecognizable character appear before, but never this... For example, the word "they're" displays as "they.re"

Any ideas? I thought it could be an encoding issue but I have 
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />`
in place.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: If it's not the part where you save the text, it must be the part where you display the text.

Comment: What is the encoding on your database?

Comment: Turns out it is the font. Had converted a font using font squirrel, and evidently it didn't play nice with the '

I changed the font and that instantly fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

As a first workaround, you could tell the content providers use the “smart” apostrophe and, for use a single quotation marks, ‘smart’ single quotes (assuming thet work OK—check it first of course). After all, the Ascii "straight" apostrophe should only be used in programming and comparable contexts, not in any normal human-language content.

It sounds like a CMS oddity, but check first that the data sent by the server actually contains “.” U+002E and not something else that just gets rendered as a period by browsers. Then you could submit a bug report to CMS provider. It might be a good idea to test the entire Ascii of characters, and why not all of Windows Latin 1 (using a page containing them all and checking that they are rendered OK, naturally with normal < and & precautions).